# Export Query result to excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

If I use the below code, I am getting the following error.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET 
   ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
   'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\Test.xls;',' SELECT top(100) company FROM AUS_DW.dbo.M_creditlimit')
```

I am able to do the same task using the code below but I am not able to get the column headers

```
USE AUS_DW

DECLARE @FileName varchar(50),
        @bcpCommand varchar(2000)

SET @FileName = 'D:\testing.txt'

SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp " SELECT top(100) * FROM AUS_DW.dbo.M_creditlimit " queryout "'
SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FileName + '" -U eoladmin -P Eol@dmin -c'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```